# I want to keep certain values the same but I want others to change automatically in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

So I have an if then statement that I am using for certain cell but I want the other cells to change.

```
if(H2,true=null!C3,null!A3,"")
```

the problem is I want to keep H2 the same when I copying and pasting it down my column but I want null!C3 and null!A3 to change. Does any know whether that is possible or not? if so how would I do this?
Also if you are wondering I did change the tags for A3 and C3 because it would still work the same if the page was called null.

Comment: will $h$2 do the trick in your IF statement? IF($h$2,TRUE bla bla bla)

Answer (score 0):

`A1` is a reletative reference
`$A$1` is an absolute reference
`$A1` is an absolute column, relative row reference
`A$1` is an relative column, absolute row reference

NOTE: If you insert a row above the row 1 or at the left of column A the reference will be changed. If you want to avoid this use `INDIRECT("A1")`